Spring authorization server widget or password credentials flow?
I'm starting a new project with Spring Authorization Server 1.3.2 to use it in a new portal that it will be developed with Angular. Clients will be able to access to it's own private area using credentials (Personal ID and password created in a previous step validating phone and email too).
Forgotten password and new user page has many functionalities that It will be hard to design it with templates in spring authorization server and implementing a new custom oauth2 flow (grant_type).
The main doubt it's if I should use the Authorization code flow with a custom login page (located in the auth server) with links to return the main web app (public pages) or develop all pages in the SPA directly. Login in that case can't use Authorization code it should be Password credentials but it's deprecated in oauth2.0, all will be in the same context without change to other subdomain like auth.domain.com
Both systems are developed internally, so there isn't third parties involved that can store maliciously the user/password.
AUTHORIZATION CODE FLOW

PASSWORD CREDENTIALS

Thanks for your help.
Regards

You should by no means use password flow (try to implement login in your Angular app). You should probably consider using an already implemented authorization server (I mean one with user registration, user profile edition, social login, advanced login flows like MFA, connection to LDAP, etc.) like Keycloak and most cloud OpenID providers (Auth0, Amazon Cognito, etc.). Last, you should not build a solution where tokens are sent to Angular: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2

I'm not referring to implementing an authentication server, I'm using the Spring Authorization Server. It's actually an authentication server dedicated to this website, it's not going to be reused to authenticate in other third-party systems. I think that under this scenario the Authorization Code flow (the recommended one) complicates the management of new users and forgotten passwords quite a bit.

That's why I wanted to know if there's a way, without leaving the web domain, to be able to embed a widget with the Spring Authorization Server login.
The other alternative would be for the SPA to collect the login like the grant_type password credentials did.

Spring Authorization Server is more of a framework to build an OpenID Provider (which are OAuth2 authorization servers). It is not an already implemented and ready to use solution like Keycloak, Auth0, American Cognito and so forth. Please take the time to learn what those are about before telling it's not what you want. Also, OAuth2 is about redirecting user to the authorization server for authentication, and then back to the OAuth2 client. It is not about including login forms in a frontend.

At most, you might give the illusion of the later with an iframe if both share the same origin (display the authorization server login and registration forms without temporarily leaving the main frontend). In the article linked above, I demo how

Thanks for the link. I've read the article and it makes sense. I'll try to do a test adapting it to what I need. Regards.

Basically, spring not recommend to do this so that it was not implemented. Any other solution is just work around

I have been digging in your aproach @ch4mp. I have some doubts how implement the session cookie storage in a high availability scenario with spring cloud gateway with your indicate SaveSession and TokenRelay. I have already configured HA for spring authorization servers (database token storage) but I can't configure a HA for the BFF.
I have tested with Apisix (with openid plugin) too but y have the same issue. Any idea how to resolve it ?. Thanks

Do as instructed in the section 2.3. of the article : use the Spring Session project. That will share the session between stateful nodes (by default in Redis). https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2#3-cost
